# es6 template literal in not supporting in firefox browser?

Tags: ecmascript-6, browser-support, template-literals

when i run below code

```
let m = "5", d = "5", y = "2015"; new Date(`${d}-${m}-${y}`);
```

firefox developer Edition v 56 return **Invalid Date** whereas Chrome v 61 return valid and right date.

> Tue May 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Does es6 template literal is not supporting in FF DE 56 browser or there is some definition vary in the browser for Date format?

Kindly suggest any link for help.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals shows that it *should* be supported. Is there any error in the console output? What happens when you output that string to console?

Comment: Try  `new Date(\`${y}-${m}-${d}\`)`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Only specific date formats are part of the standard and thus cross-browser, and that isn't one of them.

Comment: The error means that you are passing an invalid value to `Date`. Whether the value is generated via a template literal doesn't matter. (and you easily verify that by trying `new Date('5-5-2015')` instead)

Comment: @FelixKling . new Date('5-5-2015') also retrun Invalid Date . see https://imgur.com/oo3Lr6W

Comment: @Thebluefish it return Invalid Date

Comment: @StanislavKralin it gives error too even i change the order and yes we can use mm-dd-yy format too, tested in *chrome* `let m = "5", d = "5", y = "2015"; new Date(\`${d}-${m}-${y}\`);` return 
`Tue May 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not caused by template literals, this is caused by **non-standard** date formatting.

In a Firefox Developer's Edition 56 Scratchpad window:

```
(new Date(`${d}-${m}-${y}`)).toString()

/*
Invalid Date
*/

(new Date(`${y}-${m}-${d}`)).toString()

/*
Mon May 04 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)
*/
```

Here, using the format DD-MM-YYYY is **invalid**. However, using a [standard format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) of YYYY-MM-DD produces a valid date.

It appears that Chrome may allow additional formats beyond the standard. It is not advised to use non-standard formats since they are not guaranteed to be supported by all major browsers.